# Display text value in a form or a textArea, textForm by GSP and Groovy code

Tags: java, grails, web, groovy, gsp

So i have an uploadForm and after i choosed file to upload,and i submit,and therefore i want to display content of file documents to an textArea or Form,but i don't know how to get parameter to that file and render text in that file.
Here is my code:file `displayForm.gsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
</div>
<g:uploadForm action ="uploaded" >
    <input type = "file" name = "cfile" value = "File"/>
    <g:actionSubmit  action="displayForm" value = "submit" />
</g:uploadForm>
    <p>
        <textField rows="50" cols="100" value = "${cfile}"
        name="displayResult"/ >          
    </p>
    <input type="button" value = "Display" name = "Display">
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

And this is file `SampleController.groovy`:

```
class SampleController{
def f
def displayForm() {
    if(params.cfile){
        if(params.cfile instanceof        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile){                  //new FileOutputStream('D:/submitted_file.txt').leftShift( params.cfile.getInputStream() );
            f=params.cfile.transferTo(new File('D:/submitted_file.uima'));
            render file:params.cfile.toString() ,contentType: "text", encoding:"UTF-8"  
        }else{
            log.error("wrong attachment type [${cfile.getClass()}]");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above,i wan't to read file `'D:/submitted_file.uima'` and render it.
but if i call render method,it got error that file is null.

I got a problem at call file parameter from file .gsp.Should i call name "cfile" or "value" or "id" or another from uploadForm and textArea(textField).

Answer (score 0):

The `render file:x` method accepts  `byte[]`, `java.io.File` or `inputStream` parameters while you seem to be passing in a `CommonsMultipartFile`. Try calling `render file: f, ...` in the above code, instead, to actually render the file you saved to disk.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create this file, if one does not exist.

```
File file = new File("C:/test.txt");
if(!file.exists()) {
   file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: This is not true, the documentation for `transferTo` clearly states that *If the destination file already exists, it will be deleted first.*